# Display chunked mp4 from a livestream in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, api, http, mp4, hololens

I am developing a Flutter web application that needs to display a live stream from a HoloLens headset. The headset sends chunks of mp4 data. I have tried setting up a live stream solution but I get the following error: [image]

Here is the function to get the data:

```
getVideo3() async {
String username = 'username';
String password = 'password';
String basicAuth =
    'Basic ' + base64.encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
//print('1');
var request = html.HttpRequest();
request.open('GET',
    'https://' + '158.37.238.9' + '/api/holographic/stream/live.mp4');
request.setRequestHeader('authorization', basicAuth);

final completer = Completer<VideoPlayerController>();
request.onProgress.listen((html.ProgressEvent event) {
  //final response = utf8.decode(request.response);

  final blob = html.Blob([request.response]);
  final url = html.Url.createObjectUrl(blob);
  final controller = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
  controller.initialize().then((_) {
    completer.complete(controller);
  });
});
request.send();

final controller = await completer.future;

setState(() {
  _controller?.dispose();
  _controller = controller;
});
}
```

And here is the rest of the code:

```
class StreamTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const StreamTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<StreamTest> createState() => _StreamTestState();
}

class _StreamTestState extends State<StreamTest> {
  VideoPlayerController? _controller; //Fjernet null
  Future<void>? videoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //getVideo();
    getVideo3();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: ((() => Navigator.of(context).pop())),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          title: Text('Livestream'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: videoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                print('connection state done');
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Additional info:
Using the HTML package and video_player package

Comment: If the first chunk's data is causing errors then it needs to be fixed. If you don't know how, then **show the chunk data** to others for double-checking. This means **write** it as a **file** (save it as extension `.bin`) then upload it somewhere online to share.

Comment: I don't know for sure where the issue lies, but I have managed to display the content as a normal video by waiting for the connection to be done, and then displaying it, however, I need to display it in realtime. Should also mention that when doing that I used "http.get" and not "var request = html.HttpRequest();
request.open('GET',"

Comment: PS: Forgot to add... You cannot use a live **stream** with a **blob**. The blob method expects complete file data. **(1)** In HTML5 you would use MediaSource Extensions to feed incoming bytes to a player. Find a similar option in Flutter (how to connect your player to something that gives it a consistent stream of bytes back, _eg:_ with no cutting off at each progress event)... **(2)** If you want to try as blob, make sure your MP4 is fragmented. The first MP4 chunk is usually the metadata (about 700 bytes) so you need first two complete MP4 chunks to see a picture.